# How to make a time picker view in swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I successfully make `datePicker` view over my  `UITextField` in Swift. But I need to time picking in the format of `HH:MM:SS`. I have no idea about it. I need to apply picked time in time `UITextField`. so, How to make Time Picker in Swift? please refer below image. swift 2.2 , 2.0 answers also okay. Thanks lot friends!

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set the `datePickerMode` to `time`

**Swift 3**

```
self.datePicker.datePickerMode = .time
```

**Swift 2.3 or lower**

```
self.datePicker.datePickerMode = .Time
```

**Note:** This will allow you to only select `Hours` and `Minutes`, if you want to select `Seconds` also you need to go for custom time picker.

Answer (score 21):

Updated for Swift 3:

If you want to show the time picker, use the lines of code for Swift 3 below:

Variable Declarations:

```
let timePicker = UIDatePicker()
```

Method Definition:

```
func openTimePicker()  {
    timePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time
    timePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: (self.view.frame.height/2 + 60), width: self.view.frame.width, height: 150.0)
    timePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.view.addSubview(timePicker)
    timePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourViewControllerName.startTimeDiveChanged), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
}

func startTimeDiveChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    youtTextFieldName.text = formatter.string(from: sender.date)
    timePicker.removeFromSuperview() // if you want to remove time picker
}
```

Comment: problem with this is.... when you select hours and you had a sec of pause it will auto close it. anyone is trying to do this solution might want to add a flagging to the code of check if finish editting or make another viewcontroller using this method. code work. user experience need improvement. voted +1

Answer (score -1):

Added for Swift 5+

for timer (it doesn't show seconds part. )

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var timerPicker: UIDatePicker!
...
 self.timerPicker.datePickerMode = .countDownTimer
 print("countdown duration",  String(timerPicker.countDownDuration))
```

[image]